# when user type then search from two columns from ITEMS table database laravel elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, sql-like

I want to indexing data so i made command in laravel. I installed elasticsearch/elasticsearch : '^7.17' package for elastic search in laravel. i have query in laravel below:

```
public function search(string $query = ''): Collection
{
    return Item::query()
        ->where('search_name', 'like', "%{$query}%")
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")
        ->get();
}
```

so, i want to search from two fields but i did not find query in elasticsearch for that.
can you please help me?

when i have to search from one field then it is working. code for that query is:

```
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'query_string' => [
            "query" => "*".$query."*",
                "fields" => ['search_name']
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

but i want when user type like *t* then it should search from **search_name** or **name** column from Items table sql database.

sample data like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "search_name": "TR61QF",
        "name": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "search_name": "204480"
        "name": "Mirae Asset TIGER Synth-China A Leverage"
    }
]
```

when user search **t** then both result arrive in response.

Comment: Try changing `"fields" => ['search_name']` to `"fields" => ['search_name', 'name']`.

Comment: @lubosdz it is partial working but if i search '000' the in sql query 4 results come and in elasticsearch 1 result come why?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your query you need an OR condition in Elastic search API where either record match with field 1 or field 2.

You need two match queries enclosed in a bool/should query, like this

So for solving your problem you need to change the search query as per like below :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "t"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "search_name": "t"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```